# Remove the first parameter in $*

Tags: shell-script, parameter

I've got a small "logit" script;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "• $(date +%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S) • " >> "$1"
printf "%s" "$*" >> "$1"
```

This way I can create a log from anywhere to anywhere.

but! when I'm printing the $* to the log file, it does of course include the $1, but since that's the path/filename to the log, I would like to exclude it from the $*, so it don't appear on every line in the log..

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, use `shift`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "• $(date +%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S) • " >> "$1"
log="$1"
shift
printf "%s" "$*" >> "$log"
```

see man bash

> shift [n]
>
> The  positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed to $1 ....  Parameters represented by the numbers $#               down to $#-n+1 are unset.  n must be a non-negative number less than or equal to $#.  If n is 0, no  pa              rameters  are  changed.   If  n is not given, it is assumed to be 1.